# "Invalid precision value (0)" error with pyodbc and SQL Server

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pyodbc

SQLAlchemy version: 2.0.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy version: 3.0.3

I am trying to insert contact forms into my SQL server database from my python flask web app using the flask_alchemy package but I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY104', '[HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid precision value (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
[SQL: INSERT INTO [ContactForms] (first_name, last_name, email, phone, msg) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('John', 'Doe', 'johndoe@email.com', '555-555-5555', "Hello, I'd like to inquire about your services.")]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)
```

**My Model:**

```py
class ContactFormsTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "ContactForms"
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column (db.VARCHAR(25), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column (db.VARCHAR(25), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column (db.VARCHAR(75), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column (db.CHAR(12), default=None, nullable=True)
    msg = db.Column (db.TEXT, nullable=False)
```

**My insertion statement:**

```py
new_contact_form = ContactFormsTable(
            first_name="John",
            last_name="Doe",
            email="johndoe@email.com",
            phone="555-555-5555",
            msg="Hello, I'd like to inquire about your services."
        )
        db.session.add(new_contact_form)
        db.session.commit()
```

**SQL Server Table Schema:**

[image]

The schema is as it appears with `id` listed as the primary key.

I had auto increment originally set in the SQL server table but tried turning that off and still did not work. I think it has something to do with the `id` column but not sure

I tried changing the `phone` column to a `varchar(15)` but still get the same error

Everything worked fine with my connection string using vanilla `sqlalchemy` but upon here switching to `flask_sqlalchemy` and using the `db.model` instead of `sqlalchemy.Table`

My `__init__.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
from .extensions import db
from .routes.routes import pages
from .routes.api import api
import os
import pyodbc

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f'mssql+pyodbc://@{SERVER_NAME}/{DEV_DB}?driver={ODBC_18_DRIVER}&UID=USERNAME&PWD=PASSWORD' 
    db.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(pages)
    app.register_blueprint(api)
    app.secret_key = SECRET_KEY
    return app

app = create_app()
```

`extensions.py`

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

my main route:

```py
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from ..extensions import db

pages = Blueprint("pages", __name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder="static")

@pages.route('/')
def home():
    new_contact_form = ContactFormsTable(
            first_name="John",
            last_name="Doe",
            email="johndoe@email.com",
            phone="555-555-5555",
            msg="Hello, I would like to inquire about your services."
        )

    db.session.add(new_contact_form)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Comment: Add `import pyodbc; cnxn = engine.raw_connection()` to your code and then print or log the result returned by `cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME)`. What does it say?

Comment: @GordThompson I get `NameError: name 'engine' is not defined` because I have not defined an engine.

In a separate file import my `db` variable. The file has 2 lines:

`from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy` and `db = SQLAlchemy()`

I attach it to my flask application with `db.init_app(app)` in my Flask `create_app()` app creation factory in my `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Are you using the old "SQL Server" ODBC driver on Windows? If so, try installing "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" and see if that works any better.

Comment: @GordThompson we are using ODBC Driver 18. Also, I was able to get the `cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME)` but made `cnxn` by `cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connString)` which printed: `SQLSRV32.DLL`

Comment: SQLSRV32.DLL *is* the old "SQL Server" driver. "ODBC Driver 18 For SQL Server" is msodbcsql18.dll

Comment: @GordThompson oh dang thanks. I have updated now to driver version 18 and I have got the connection string working with PYODBC. But now I am getting the original error I had specified above. We tested the exact SQL statement in our Microsoft SQL Server Studio and it worked fine but for some reason it is not working here.

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson I am using version 3.0.3. I have also added more code above to my post for more context. One thing that confuses me is that I set my connection string using a username and password but when I put the wrong password I do not get an error and still get the same original error.

Comment: 3.0.3 is the version of Flask-SQLAlchemy. I'm asking about the version of SQLAlchemy itself. (2.0.1 is the latest version, released this morning.)

Comment: Oops sorry, I do not really use the normal SQLAlchemy package in my code, although, I did install it earlier when you wanted me to test what ODBC version I was using and that version is the newest 2.0.1.

Comment: Ah, okay. I also just noticed that the link at the end of the error messages says `https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi`, indicating that you are using SQLAlchemy 2.0.

Comment: "Everything worked fine with my connection string using vanilla sqlalchemy but upon here switching to flask_sqlalchemy and using the db.model instead of sqlalchemy.Table" - So that, combined with the fact that [my vanilla SQLAlchemy ORM code](https://gist.github.com/44cf437776119d99c4b2b8ad92e1f760) works fine, suggests that this is not a SQLAlchemy issue *per se*.

Comment: @GordThompson after stepping away for some time and coming back with a clear mind I realized in the actual code one of the driver had not changed in our `.env` file to version 18. Thanks for your help I will continue with it tomorrow. Good to know it is not an issue with SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was caused by using the ancient "SQL Server" ODBC driver (SQLSRV32.DLL) that ships with Windows.

It was resolved by installing "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server" and using that.